# active state adding to parent link on one, but not another

Tags: jquery

I'm using this script to add an "active" class to my menu items. One of my parent menu items is /path/library/. The class is added just fine there. And then on the pagination of that page (i.e., /path/library/?page-2) the class stays added to the parent just fine. For the parent link /path/signage/, the active link is applied just fine. But when I have a non-paginated child (i.e., /path/signage/posters/) no active link is applied anywhere. I'm lost. No idea why I can't get it to work properly when it does it right for one but not the other.

Here's my script...

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
       $('.persist-header a').each(function () {
          var $this = $(this);
          if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(window.location.pathname) !== -1) {
             $this.addClass('active');
          }
       });
    });
```

EDIT
Ok, here's my header code (this is a WP site. And since I'm pulling images from specific taxonomies, I'm not using the WP menu system - I'm using ACF for selecting the items that go in the menu).

```
    <div class="d-flex align-items-end">
        <div class="content container-fluid" style="padding: 0 !important;">

            <style>
                        .bordercolor0 {
                            border-color: #26b59c;
                        }
                        .bordercolor1 {
                            border-color: #f99d3f;
                        }
                        .bordercolor2 {
                            border-color: #d52352;
                        }
                        .bordercolor3 {
                            border-color: #ef453b;
                        }
                        .bordercolor4 {
                            border-color: #000000;
                        }
                        .bordercolorhome {
                            border-color: #000000;
                        }
                    </style>

            <!-- MAIN NAV -->
            <nav role="navigation" class="cblNavMenu persist-area">

                <?php  ?>

                <div class="cblNavMenu--wrap static persist-header ">

                    <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

                        if( have_rows('choose_top_level_category', 'option') ):

                        $c = 0;

                        while( have_rows('choose_top_level_category', 'option') ): the_row();

                        // vars
                        $term = get_sub_field('category', 'option');
                        $cat_label = get_sub_field('category_label', 'option');
                        $current_term_id = $term->term_id;
                         ?>

                    <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max  <?php echo int_to_words($c); ?> " href="<?php echo esc_url( get_term_link( $term ) ); ?>" role="button">
                        <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
                            <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">

                                <?php $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                    'posts_per_page' => 1,
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                        array(
                                            'taxonomy' => 'mediacat',
                                            'terms' => $term->term_id,
                                        )
                                    ),
                                    'orderby' => 'rand',
                                    'post_status' => 'inherit',
                                    //'fields' => 'ids'
                                );
                                $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) :

                                    $loop->the_post();

                                    $item = get_the_id();

                                    $attachment_image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $item, 'square' );
                                ?>

                                <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
                                    <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="<?php echo $attachment_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $term->name;?>"/>
                                </figure>
                                <?php endwhile;
                                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                            </div>
                            <span class="cblNavMenu--label"><?php if($cat_label) { echo $cat_label; } else { echo $term->name; } ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </a>

                        <?php $c++; endwhile;
                    endif; ?>

                    <script>
                        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                            $('.persist-header a').each(function () {
                                var $this = $(this);
                                if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(window.location.pathname) !== -1) {
                                    $this.addClass('active');
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    </script>

                    <script>
                        jQuery(function($) {
                            if ($('.zero.active').length > 0) {
                                $('.cblNavMenu--wrap').addClass('bordercolor0');
                            }
                            if ($('.one.active').length > 0) {
                                $('.cblNavMenu--wrap').addClass('bordercolor1');
                            }
                            if ($('.two.active').length > 0) {
                                $('.cblNavMenu--wrap').addClass('bordercolor2');
                            }
                            if ($('.three.active').length > 0) {
                                $('.cblNavMenu--wrap').addClass('bordercolor3');
                            }
                            if ($('.four.active').length > 0) {
                                $('.cblNavMenu--wrap').addClass('bordercolor4');
                            }
                            if ($('.zero.active').length > 0) {
                                $('footer').addClass('bordercolor0');
                            }
                            if ($('.one.active').length > 0) {
                                $('footer').addClass('bordercolor1');
                            }
                            if ($('.two.active').length > 0) {
                                $('footer').addClass('bordercolor2');
                            }
                            if ($('.three.active').length > 0) {
                                $('footer').addClass('bordercolor3');
                            }
                            if ($('.four.active').length > 0) {
                                $('footer').addClass('bordercolor4');
                            }
                            if ($('body.home').length > 0) {
                                $('footer').addClass('bordercolorhome');
                            }
                        });
                    </script>

                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </nav>

        </div>
    </div>
```

And my taxonomy page, which is working great for paginated children, but not regular children (of course the get_header and get_footer codes are in there as well. Seemed superfluous to include them here though)...

```
    <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(''); ?>>
        <div class="content container-fluid" style="padding: 0 !important;">
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <?php $term = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var( 'term' ), get_query_var( 'taxonomy' ) );

                    $paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

                    $current_term_id = $term->term_id;
                    $current_name = $term->name;
                    $current_taxonomy = $term->taxonomy;
                    $current_parent = $term->parent;
                    ?>

                    <h1 class="header__title">
                        <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
                        <?php echo $current_name; ?>
                    </h1>

                    <?php $sub_terms = get_terms( array(
                        'taxonomy' => $current_taxonomy,
                        'child_of' => $current_term_id,
                        'hide_empty' => true,
                    ) );

                    if ($sub_terms) {
                    ?>
                    <ul class="sub-terms">
                        <?php foreach ($sub_terms as $sub_term) { ?>
                        <li><a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $sub_term ) ?>" class="sub"><?php echo $sub_term->name?></a></li>
                        <?php }// END foreach ?>
                    </ul><!-- END .sub-terms -->
                    <?php }// END if ?>

                    <main>
                        Search Form Here

                        <div class="container-fluid">
                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="pagination_links" style="clear: both;">
                                    <?php $args = array(
                                            'post_type' => 'attachment',
                                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                            'tax_query'       => array(
                                                array(
                                                    'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
                                                    'field' => 'term_id',
                                                    'terms' => $current_term_id
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            'orderby' => 'title',
                                            'order' => 'asc',
                                            'posts_per_page' => '20',
                                            'paged' => $paged,
                                            'post_status' => 'inherit'
                                        );

                                        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

                                        $c = 0;

                                    ?>
                                    <?php $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                                        for ($i=1;$i<=$loop->max_num_pages;$i++) { ?>
                                            <a href="<?php str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ) ?>?page=<?php echo $i; ?>" class="page-numbers current" aria-current="page">Page <?php echo $i; ?></a>

                                        <?php }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <form class="wpsp-page-nav-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="get" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
                                        <label for="sortby" class="wpsp-label wpsp-hidden" style="display: inline-block;"><?php _e('Jump to', 'wp-smart-pagination'); ?></label>
                                        <input class="wpsp-input-number" type="text" placeholder="page..."  size="15" name="page" style="display: inline-block; width: auto; background-color: #fff;"/>
                                        <button class="btn" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="container-fluid">

                                    <div class="grid">
                                        <div class="grid-sizer"></div>
                                        <?php $c = 0;
                                            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {

                                            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                                                $loop->the_post();

                                                $item = get_the_id();
                                                $atts = wp_get_attachment_image_src($item, 'large');
                                                $image_all = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($item);
                                                $attachment_page = wp_get_attachment_url( $item );
                                                $title = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($item);
                                                $image_title = wp_prepare_attachment_for_js($item);
                                        ?>

                                        <div class="grid-item">

                                            <div class="entry-title-box">
                                                <h3 class="entry-title"><?php echo $image_title['title']; ?></h3>
                                            </div>
                                            <img src="<?php echo $atts[0]; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image_all['alt']; ?>">
                                            <div class="entry-content-box">
                                                <p>keywords: <em><?php if (empty($image_all['alt'])) { echo $image_all['caption']; } else { echo $image_all['alt']; } ?></em></p>
                                                <div id="fileName<?php echo $loop->current_post +1; ?>" style="display: none;"><?php echo $image_title['title']; ?></div>
                                                <div class="btn-group">
                                                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn2 js-tooltip" id="btnCopy" rel="fileName<?php echo $loop->current_post +1; ?>" type="button" data-toggle="popover" title="copied">Copy Filename</button>
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn2 js-tooltip" id="btnCopy" rel="fileName" type="button" data-toggle="popover" title="copied">
                                                        <!-- icon from google's material design library -->
                                                        <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                                            <path d="M17,9H7V7H17M17,13H7V11H17M14,17H7V15H14M12,3A1,1 0 0,1 13,4A1,1 0 0,1 12,5A1,1 0 0,1 11,4A1,1 0 0,1 12,3M19,3H14.82C14.4,1.84 13.3,1 12,1C10.7,1 9.6,1.84 9.18,3H5A2,2 0 0,0 3,5V19A2,2 0 0,0 5,21H19A2,2 0 0,0 21,19V5A2,2 0 0,0 19,3Z" />
                                                        </svg>
                                                    </button>
                                                </div>
                                                <button id="btn_link" class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#galleryModal<?php echo $loop->current_post +1; ?>" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" style="margin-top: 5px;">Suggest keywords</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                        <!-- Modal -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="galleryModal<?php echo $loop->current_post +1; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="galleryModalLabel<?php echo $loop->current_post +1; ?>" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body d-flex h-100">
                                                        <div class="row justify-content-center align-self-center">
                                                            <div class="col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                                                                <img src="<?php echo $atts[0]; ?>" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail">
                                                            </div>
                                                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                    <h2 class="modal-title" id="galleryModalLabel<?php echo $loop->current_post +1; ?>"><span id="copyit"><?php echo $image_title['title']; ?></span></h2>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="row">
                                                                    <p>keywords: <em><?php if (empty($image_all['alt'])) { echo $image_all['caption']; } else { echo $image_all['alt']; } ?></em></p>
                                                                </div>
                                                                <div class="row" id="message">
                                                                    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[gravityform id="1" field_values="filename='. $image_title['title'] .'" ajax="true"]' ); ?>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-footer">
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                                <?php } $c++; } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                                    </div>

                                    <script type="text/javascript">
                                        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                                            // init Masonry
                                            var $grid = $('.grid').masonry({
                                            itemSelector: '.grid-item',
                                            percentPosition: true,
                                            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
                                        });

                                        // layout Masonry after each image loads
                                        $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
                                            $grid.masonry();
                                        });
                                    });

                                    jQuery(document).on("click", "#btnCopy", function(ev) {
                                        var $body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
                                        var rel = jQuery(this).attr("rel");
                                        var text = jQuery("#"+rel).text();
                                        var $tempInput = document.createElement('INPUT');
                                        $body.appendChild($tempInput);
                                        $tempInput.setAttribute('value',  text)
                                        $tempInput.select();
                                        document.execCommand('copy');
                                        $body.removeChild($tempInput);
                                    });

                                    jQuery(function () {
                                        jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover().click(function () {
                                            setTimeout(function () {
                                                jQuery('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover('hide');
                                            }, 2000);
                                        });
                                    });
                                </script>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <div class="pagination_links" style="clear: both;">
                                    <?php $big = 999999999; // need an unlikely integer

                                        for ($i=1;$i<=$loop->max_num_pages;$i++) { ?>
                                            <a href="<?php str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ) ?>?page=<?php echo $i; ?>" class="page-numbers current" aria-current="page">Page <?php echo $i; ?></a><?php }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                                <form class="wpsp-page-nav-form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];?>" method="get" style="text-align: center;">
                                    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
                                        <label for="sortby" class="wpsp-label wpsp-hidden" style="display: inline-block;"><?php _e('Jump to', 'wp-smart-pagination'); ?></label>
                                        <input class="wpsp-input-number" type="text" placeholder="page..."  size="15" name="page" style="display: inline-block; width: auto; background-color: #fff;"/>
                                        <button class="btn" type="submit" style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fa fa-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Would have to guess that, in the "non-paginated child" case, either (a) no elements match '.persist-header a' or (b) you are victim of CSS specificity (ie jQuery is doing its thing but your CSS is wrongly structured).

Comment: No, .persist-header a exists on all pages - it's part of the header. and jquery is in the header file as well. Once there's an 'active' class applied (which it isn't on the /path/signage/posters page, I've checked, to make sure there wasn't something wrong with my CSS), then another script checks to see which menu item has that 'active' state added. Each menu item is numbered (zero to five). So when, for instance, in this case, it should have .three.active, a style is added to a div above .persist-header (in this case, called nav-wrap). Do you need to see more code?

Comment: More code might  help.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - code added above.

Comment: So add `console.log($this.attr('href'), window.location.pathname);` to the `.each()` loop where the `active` class is added. Do the `href` and `pathname` match in the way you expect, on a non-paginated page?

Comment: Hmmmm...the paginated page (?page=2) shows imagetags/library but the child page that is not working is showing imagetags/signage/posters

(I'm not sure how to read console logs, so this is from FireFox Debugger). So apparently my jQuery is really only reading the ?page=2 as part of the original page URL, which is why it's showing the 'active' state properly. But I'm not sure how then to correct the code to work for the actual child pages.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207724/discussion-between-roamer-1888-and-laura-sage).

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution by posing a different version of the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230203/trying-to-add-class-to-an-attribute-based-on-current-string-in-current-url#60230239) since my original problem changed when I got my pagination issue resolved so it was no longer doing "path/term/?page=2", but had changed to "path/term/page/2", and I was also still having difficulty with applying the style when I was on child pages like "path/term/sub-term".

```
    $('.persist-header a[href*="/<?php echo $term2->slug; ?>/"]').addClass('active');
```

It works great!