# Trying to add class to an attribute based on current string in current URL

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to get this to work all morning, with no luck.

If I do the following code:

```
    $('.persist-header a').each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       if (window.location.href.indexOf('signage') !== -1) {
          $this.addClass('active');
       }
    });
```

It applies the active2 class to all a href's under .persist-header.

I want it to only apply it to the one URL in the bunch with the term indicated (signage) in it.

I've tried all sorts of combos, but none are achieving the desired effect. This, for instance, returns nothing at all:

```
    $('.persist-header a').each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);
       if ($this.attr('href').window.location.href.indexOf('signage') > -1) {
          $this.addClass('active');
       }
    });
```

jQuery is not my strong suit. Any help you can afford will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
The first suggestion below worked for me. But the 2nd throws an 'active' state on all of the links. So I'm providing my html below:

```
    <div class="cblNavMenu--wrap static persist-header ">
       <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item zero active" href="path/imagetags/library/" role="button">
          <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
             <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
                <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
                   <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Library"/>
                </figure>
             </div>
             <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Library</span>
          </div>
       </a>

       <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item one active" href="path/imagetags/this_that/" role="button">
          <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
             <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
                <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
                   <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="This &amp; That"/>
                </figure>
             </div>
             <span class="cblNavMenu--label">This/That</span>
          </div>
       </a>

       <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item two active" href="path/imagetags/socialmedia/" role="button">
          <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
             <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
                <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
                   <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Social Media"/>
                </figure>
             </div>
             <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Social</span>
          </div>
       </a>

       <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item three active" href="path/imagetags/signage/" role="button">
          <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
             <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
                <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
                   <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Signage"/>
                </figure>
             </div>
             <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Signage</span>
          </div>
       </a>

       <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item four active" href="path/imagetags/properties/" role="button">
          <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
             <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
                <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
                   <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Properties"/>
                </figure>
             </div>
             <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Properties</span>
          </div>
       </a>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$this.attr('href').window`  Is not a thing.  `window` is the top level element in the DOM, accessable by javascript.  It is not a child of anything, save for an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `window.location.href` in the second version.

```
if ($this.attr('href').indexOf('signage') > -1)
```

You can also put that in the selector and get rid of the loop:

```js
$('.persist-header a[href*=signage]').addClass('active');
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: pink;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cblNavMenu--wrap static persist-header">
  <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item zero" href="path/imagetags/library/" role="button">
    <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
      <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
        <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
          <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Library" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Library</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item one" href="path/imagetags/this_that/" role="button">
    <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
      <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
        <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
          <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="This &amp; That" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <span class="cblNavMenu--label">This/That</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item two" href="path/imagetags/socialmedia/" role="button">
    <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
      <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
        <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
          <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Social Media" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Social</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item three" href="path/imagetags/signage/" role="button">
    <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
      <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
        <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
          <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Signage" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Signage</span>
    </div>
  </a>

  <a class="cblNavMenu--link navBtn max menu-item four" href="path/imagetags/properties/" role="button">
    <div class="cblNavMenu--link__content block">
      <div class="cblNavMenu--icon">
        <figure class="cblNavMenu--icon__imgwrap">
          <img class="cblNavMenu--icon__img" src="path/image.jpg" alt="Properties" />
        </figure>
      </div>
      <span class="cblNavMenu--label">Properties</span>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! The first one worked like a charm! (the second did not, for some reason).

Comment: I see that. I can't get it to work for me though. It's throwing an active class on all the href's when I do it that way.

Comment: Update the question with your HTML and indicate which ones should get the class.

Comment: I've updated it with the results from the 2nd, shorter, snippet that you provided. Like I said though, the first one you provided worked like a charm, so I ain't mad. In fact, I'm extremely grateful!

Comment: All your `<a>` tags already have `active` in their classes. Is there something that's supposed to remove those before adding it to the `signage` element?

Comment: No, that's what happened when I used the code. They don't have the active state otherwise.

Comment: I wanted to see the original HTML before the code runs. The code changes the DOM, it doesn't change the HTML.

Comment: But I think I've discovered the problem (and I don't know how to solve it): My domain has the term "library" in it. And so when on the page "path/library", it sees the word in every url. How can I limit it to only an instance with a hash on either side?

Comment: You mean `href*="/library/"`?

Comment: But you should have the same problem with `indexOf`.

Comment: ARGHHHH see, I didn't think to use the quotes around the word when I tried adding the hashes. Now it works PERFECT! (one day I'll take the time to really learn jQuery). I really can't thank you enough! It's fantastic now!